# Maven: How a project can be able to reference a class from a secondary previous dependency

Tags: java, maven

I am working with Maven and creating my own modules.

I have the **01CentralDomain** project
with the simple **com.manuel.jordan.domain** package with three @Entities
one of them is for example **Product**

Part of its pom.xml is:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
<artifactId>central-domain</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralDomain</name>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<url>https://github.com/manueljordan/</url>
```

I have the other **02CentralDomain** project
again with the same simple **com.manuel.jordan.domain** package with two new @Entities
one of them is for example **User**

Consider this how an extension of the first project

Part of its pom.xml is:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
<artifactId>central-domain</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>02CentralDomain</name>
<version>1.0.2</version>
<url>https://github.com/manueljordan/</url>
...
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Therefore practically my second project has access to the first project, it about to be able to reference the three entities, like **Product**, we can assume my **domain** package now has a total of 5 entities, 3 from the first + 2 for the second.

Now I have a third project (02CentralExecution)

Part of its pom.xml is:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralexecution</groupId>
<artifactId>central-execution</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>02CentralExecution</name>
<version>1.0.2</version>
<url>https://github.com/manueljordan/</url>
...
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Theoretically the third project has access to the second project source code and **therefore** for the first project source code too.

It does not work, the third project only can access the second project source code.
I can use the **User** class but not the **Product** class.

Even if I declare both

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

It does not work.

How I can get working this?

Comment: You can't have the same artifact in two different versions.

Comment: Each module can only have one version of a dependency it builds against.  This is not just a limitation of maven, but of Java.  There is no way to tell it which classes use one version and which classes use the other.  Note: with OSGi you can load multiple versions of a library, but still each module can only use one version.

Comment: Oh sad to read that, I thought Maven was able to get reference to the first project through the second… I want avoid do a copy and paste from the first project into the second and have all working well..it is my latest solution but not very suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different artifactId's. Maven considers (roughly) groupId:artifactId as the "primary key" for your module, and if you depend on two different versions of module XXX:YYY  then it will just include the "most appropiate one", which is usually the one with the higher version.

Furthermore, it turns out that two different modules is what you actually want, as you do not really have two versions of the same module, but a module X that depends on a different one Y, and a third module Z that depends on both X and Y (direct dependency on X, and indirect dependency on Y through X).

So if you have:

01CentralDomain pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
<artifactId>central-domain-01</artifactId><!-- note renamed artifactId -->
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralDomain</name>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<url>https://github.com/manueljordan/</url>
```

02CentralDomain pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
<artifactId>central-domain-02</artifactId><!-- note renamed artifactId -->
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>02CentralExecution</name>
<version>1.0.1</version><!-- Not a higher version, but a different module!!! -->
<url>https://github.com/manueljordan/</url>
...
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain-01</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

02CentralExecution pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralexecution</groupId>
<artifactId>central-execution</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>02CentralExecution</name>
<version>1.0.1</version><!-- Version 1.0.2 makes no sense now, just use 1.0.1 -->
<url>https://github.com/manueljordan/</url>
...
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain-02</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Then everything should "just work"

Comment: Thank you, it works, I am wondered about this behaviour. Yes, I have assumed the groupId:artifactId was the "key", but according **just** with the version, I should be able to get working my first solution.

Comment: I thought all was transitive according the "cascade" of dependencies according "identifying" each dependency through the version

Comment: Your first solution cannot work. Maven will only include a single version of groupId:artificatId[:type[:classifier]] as a dependency, because it sees different versions of  groupId:artificatId[:type[:classifier]] as *conflicting*.

Comment: Again, as a big *simplification*, think that you should be able to change  version X of an artifact with, say, version X+1 and it should work, because the higher version by itself would contain everything the lower version contains (plus bugfixes, plus additional features, ...). Then, if you want to *build on* what that artifact provides, create a *different* artifact (meaning, different groupId:artifactId[:type[:classifier]] and specify a dependency on the first artifact

Comment: Thanks again by your valuable explanation. Understood